# В Excel как можно текст заменить на уникальный номер или на хэш значения

Tags: excel, vba

Доброго времени суток! В Excel как можно изменить Ф.И.О и ИНН на хэш - значения, либо на другие уникальные значения с помощью макроса ?

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать что-то типа такого:

```
Private Function EasyHash(ByRef Str$) As Long
Dim i As Integer, Hash As Long
For i = 1 To Len(Str)
        Hash = i + 1664525 * AscB(Mid(Str, i, 1)) + 1013904223
        EasyHash = (Hash / i And 1048575) + EasyHash
Next
End Function
```

Разница:

Алла | 2036555

аллА | 1090691

баа | 2089824

ааб | 980141

Оригинал - http://www.excelworld.ru/forum/2-917-10187-16-1319802770